# Dependable Drop Down Menus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After creating three dependable drop down menus using jquery,ajax and php.
After my dropdown menus have already been populated, for example when i select a value in the first drop down menu, the second drop down menu is created based on the first selected value and so on with the third drop down menu when i select a value in the second drop down menu.  Now how to capture the selected values again altogether to perform further queries on the database.

Comment: set the same class name for all select box and run each function to get all the selected values like this $('.qm_SELECT_sel').change(function(){

 $('.qm_SELECT_sel option:selected').each(function(){ 
    
    alert($(this).val());  
 
  }); 
  
});

Comment: Please provide a verifiable example.

Comment: But how to capture these selected values in php again to perform further queries on the database. – Nivin Sunathree 6 mins ago    
     
because my drop down menus are already populated using data from the database. now i want to capture the selected values altogether to perform further queries on the database – Nivin Sunathree 6 secs ago   edit

Comment: show your some of code

Answer (score 1):

Set the same class name for all select box and every change in select box run the function  and run each function which all selected to get all the selected values like this

```js
               
       dropdown1 ='';
        dropdown2 ='';
         dropdown3 ='';

      $('.qm_SELECT_sel').change(function(){
   
      // $all_drop_down_values =[];


  $('.qm_SELECT_sel option:selected').each(function(){ 
    
    if($(this).val()!='' &&  $(this).attr('name')=='dropdown1')
      {
         dropdown1 =$(this).val();
 
      }
      if($(this).val()!='' &&  $(this).attr('name')=='dropdown2')
      {
         dropdown2 =$(this).val();
 
      }
       if($(this).val()!='' &&  $(this).attr('name')=='dropdown3')
      {
         dropdown3 =$(this).val();
 
      }
   }); 
    
     if(dropdown1!='' && dropdown3 !='' && dropdown3 !='')
      {
           $.ajax({ 
              url: 'your_destination_page.php',
             type:'POST',
             data:{dropdown1:dropdown1,dropdown2:dropdown2,dropdown3:dropdown3},
            success:function(data)
            {
                 alert("hi");
             }
            
            
           });
      }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="dropdown1"  class="qm_SELECT_sel">
      <option value=""  >select 1 </option>
       <option value="1" >1 </option>
       <option value="2" >2</option>
      </select>

    <select name="dropdown2" class="qm_SELECT_sel" >
      <option value="" >select 2 </option>
       <option value="1" >1 </option>
       <option value="2" >2</option>
      </select>

     <select name="dropdown3" class="qm_SELECT_sel" >
      <option value="" >select 2 </option>
       <option value="1" >1 </option>
       <option value="2" >2</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: But how to capture these selected values in php again to perform further queries on the database.

Comment: because my drop down menus are already populated using data from the database. now i want to capture the selected values altogether to perform further queries on the database

Comment: you just submit the form it will post the data with respective name you will get the values like $_POST['select_box_name1'];

Comment: No i cant use submit button because it will reload the page, and i will lose all the selected values. I have to keep them in the variables till the end.  After my drop down menus have been populated, i want to use the selected values to generate my tables from the database. Do you have an email add for me to send you the code. thanks

Comment: \Can you help me with the ajax please?

Comment: what your going to do with these all drop down values ? please explain i will give some points

Comment: Actually only the selected values from the drop down list, that i'm going to use to perform further queries on the database. with the code that you have given me above, its giving an alert, every time i select a value on the drop down menu. how to use the code, to capture all three selected values using ajax and php

Comment: In the above code, you have the same classes qm_SELECT_sel for the drop down, how do i use that now to do the ajax

Comment: Can you help me with the ajax

Comment: in your_destination_page.php  you will get the value by print_r( $_POST); there you can do your process at you just echo something to return the ajax call.

Comment: i can post one value at a time, but i dont know how to post  several values at the same time using ajax, can you help me on that? with the ajax

Comment: already i updated my answer with as you expected  check it that

Comment: with the code that you have give me above, can you write the ajax code as well.Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot , i try the code that you have given me and let you know

Comment: Hi! JYoThI, Actually its not working, can you help on that?

Comment: Ive used the same code that you have given me, but its not alerting the hi

Comment: did you created your_destination_page.php page and echo anything there ?  like echo $_POST['dropdown1'];

Comment: When i posted only one value, its alerting the hi, but the not three, can you help me on that?

Comment: Ive tried posting the three variables at the same time, but unfortunately, it doesnt work